# Tensor operator

Tags: matrices, tensors

I have come across the following expression:

H:E

where, H = e(levi-cita symbol)*a constant which means a 3rd order tensor with 27 components

E = 2nd order tensor,

now, what does H:E mean? I know that the result has to be a vector (3 components).

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: is it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadics#Double-dot_product ?

Comment: @janmarqz There are two double dot products $A:B$ and $A..B$. In a Cartesian basis, they are $A_{ij}B_{ij}$ and $A_{ij}B_{ji}$, but some authors use the opposite convention. They give different results, in general, unless one of the tensors is symmetric.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $E=E_{ij}\textbf{e}^i\textbf{e}^j$ is a symmetric tensor such that $E_{ij}=E_{ji}$, So you have:
$$H^{ijk}=\alpha\cdot\epsilon^{ijk}$$
$$E=E_{ij}$$
In order to produce a first order tensor (vector) with three components, we arrange the tensors in such a way to produce a vector, with components $V^i$:
$$H:E=H^{ijk}E_{jk}=V^i$$
So therefore:
$$V^i=\alpha\cdot\epsilon^{ijk}E_{jk}=\alpha\cdot\epsilon^{ijk}E_{kj}$$